# How to remove the .00 decimal from the shopping cart & Invoice of magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, currency

I am building an ecommerce website named [bookslab.in](http://bookslab.in).

I want to remove the **.00 decimals** from the all **products prices** that i am adding in the shopping cart & in Invoice generated.

I am using the **ET currency manager**, it removes the prices decimals of all the products **except the shopping cat products & Invoice**

Is there any way to remove the decimals from the shopping cart products & from Invoices & to convert the main price without decimals. I want my grand total without the decimals.

My store currency in **Indian Rupees.

I am attaching the screenshot. Do i require any changes.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288819/how-to-remove-decimal-from-magento-1-prices) solution ?

Comment: I had don the changes in currency.phtml, but it does work?

Comment: I have installed magento 1.9.3.8 and the next route does not appear and I can not delete the decimals either `4)\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php line 1358: public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
{ return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 0, $addBrackets);
}` thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change price precision in magento you would need to overwrite some core files.

In the example below we are changing precision to 0.

1) Overwrite `lib/Zend/Currency.php` and change precision around line:

```
 protected $_options = array(
     'position'  => self::STANDARD,
     'script'    => null,
     'format'    => null,
     'display'   => self::NO_SYMBOL,
     'precision' => 0,    /*CHANGE*/
     'name'      => null,
     'currency'  => null,
     'symbol'    => null,
     'locale'    => null,
     'value'     => 0,
     'service'   => null,
     'tag'       => 'Zend_Locale'
 );
```

2) overwrite `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` and change roundPrice function:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{    
    return round($price, 0);
}
```

3) overwrite `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php` and change format function:

```
public function format($price,$options=array(),$includeContainer = true,$addBrackets = false)
{   
  return $this->formatPrecision( $price,0,$options,$includeContainer,$addBrackets);
}
```

4)`\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` line 1358:

```
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 0, $addBrackets);
}
```

Comment: Okzz i will check & get back to you

Comment: I had made the changes in all 3 files as you instructed, but still .00 comes in shopping cart & invoice of order

Comment: clear cache @SalmanDalal

Comment: i had clear but results are the same no changes

Comment: Its working at my side @SalmanDalal

Comment: but its not working at my side @Gopal Patel

Comment: Just disable above mentioned extension

Comment: Yeap it works of me to remove the decimals from shopping cart, but on invoice decimals are still visible

Comment: Find Updated code @SalmanDalal

Comment: Yeap Cool @Gopal Patel for helping me & in future stay connected. 
It works for me.

Comment: You can upvote the answer so that it can be helpful to others @SalmanDalal

Comment: Yeap no problem.